# mysql remote server access from C# application

Tags: c#, mysql

I have done a small C# Win Forms application, that connects to mySQL database using mySQLconnector. This works perfectly ok with my localhost.

```
String ConnectionString = "server=xx.xxx.xx.xxx;uid=myuserid;pwd=mypassword;database=dbname";
```

But I do get following error when I try to connect to remote server:
Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
{"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it xx.xxx.xx.xxx:3306"}

I have pinged the server from command prompt and I get response. 
I also verified mySQL server settings in remote server database (correct name/ip, portno:3306, skip networking:OFF)

The remote server is accessible without any problem from web server that runs php script and uses same settings as  the connection sting I listed above.

The mySQL server is hosted on external shared hosting company 123reg.co.uk with me logging to phpmyadmin using same uid/passwd as like in connection string.
I can't understand what is different between webserver accessing OK, but my C# app having trouble with it??

Can any one please help...

Thanks in Advance
Sam

Comment: Have you tried to telnet [server ip] [port] and see if it works?

Comment: It is likely that 123reg don't allow you connect directly to the mysql server, and it will be hidden behind a firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Your ip address will be different from the web server.
If your ip address is static you can grant access to your ip address within your mysql database ( https://www.google.com.au/search?q=mysql+grant+access+to+user+from+host ).
I'd recommend using the server to access the database and make your c# application talk to your webserver using ajax/json calls ( https://www.google.com.au/search?q=C%23+Win+Forms+ajax+json ) - that way you're not tied to an ip address for access.
Alternatively you can look at setting up ssh tunnels to your webserver if remote shell access is available so you can get the same access as your webserver. ( https://www.google.com.au/search?q=ssh+tunnels+example+mysql That's what I do myself)

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with servers setup so they won't accept remote connections. This is for security reasons mainly. Some places will let you enable it in the CP, but if you have direct access to the server, you should be able to follow these steps.

http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/mysql-connect-to-your-database-remotely